# How to do the correct casting using a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, casting

The objective is to write a program that will increase the population every 7 and 35 seconds and decrease every 13 seconds. I am trying to use a loop for this program and I am having some problems with getting the right casting for each variable. Here's the code:

```
#(1)There is a birth every 7 seconds (2)There is a death every 13 seconds (3)There is a new    
immigrant every 35 seconds.
#CURRENT POP: 307,357,870

populationCurrent = input("What is the current population")
x=0
while x!=100:
    if (x%7==0):
        populationCurrent=populationCurrent+1
        x=x+1
    elif (x%13==0):
        populationCurrent=populationCurrent-1
        x=x+1
    elif (x%35==0):
        populationCurrent+=1
        x=x+1
    else:
        x=x+1
print("The population will be "+int(populationCurrent)+".")
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Python doesn't have type casting.

Comment: Python does not have casting per se.

Comment: `x = x + 1` is executed for *every branch*. You can just move that out of the `if` statements and not repeat yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Is your code not running, or not giving you the expected result?  It looks like you never decrement the population.

Comment: Your code also handles the various events incorrectly. They are *not exclusive*; 35 is divisible by 7 too, but your code either has a birth *or* an immigration. At 91 seconds, there should be both a birth and a death, but your code will only register a birth at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused in python2 and python3, there's a difference in input() function of python 2.x and python 3.x, where input() function gives an integer value in python 2 and str in python 3

Answer (score 1):

1. `input()` is str by default so, this should be converted to int

   `populationCurrent = str(input("What is the current population"))`
2. You cannot concatenate string and `int`

   `print("The population will be "+str(populationCurrent)+".")`
3. Its easier to do this than iterate through 100 times

   `populationCurrent += 100//7 + 100//35 - 100//13`

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I tested it without the int-cast, it returns float, converting `populationCurrent` itself to float

Comment: if you do `//` it should floor it to an int ... (see http://ideone.com/BclA4S) (although its not a big deal either way results in the correct solution :P)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `populationCurrent` to an integer immediately after you read the string.

```
populationCurrent = int(input("What is the current population"))
```

Note that if you don't enter a string that is a valid integer representation, this will raise a `ValueError`. You might want to consider how to handle that (catch it and use a default value? catch it and try to read another value? Let the exception propagate?)

With this change, you'll have to convert the integer value back to a string for the output:

```
print("The population will be "+str(populationCurrent)+".")
```

or using any of the various string formatting tools available. It's better to have `populationCurrent` as an integer, since there are more places in your code that assume it to be an integer than assume it to be a string.

Comment: The `print()` call will also fail.

Comment: Next problem: at (7 * 13) = 91 seconds, there is both a death *and* a birth.. And every 35 seconds there is birth *and* an immigration.

Comment: That's a problem, but independent of the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is convert populationCurrent from string to int:

```
populationCurrent = int(input("What is the current population?"))
```

The more concerning stuff is that your code doesn't do what it's supposed to: when x is 35 you will only have one birth, since 35 % 7 is 0, but no immigrant will arrive. Do something like this, removing the elif statements which do not make the code that more efficient anyway:

```
while x!=100:
    if (x%7==0):
        populationCurrent=populationCurrent+1
    if (x%13==0):
        populationCurrent=populationCurrent-1
    if (x%35==0):
        populationCurrent+=1
    x=x+1
print("The population will be ", populationCurrent, ".")
```

Though still note that the loop will stop after x gets to 100. You could reset it but I don't know for how long you want it to run.

Comment: fixed so it includes the printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def intInput(prompt):
    while 1:
        try: return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError: print("Invalid Input!")

def YearToModifier(x):
    if x%35 ==0 or x%7 ==0: return 1
    if x%13 == 0: return -1
    return 0

populationCurrent = intInput("What is the current population?") #ensure you get an int
n_years = intInput("How Many Years?") #ensure you get an int
#in this case populationChange is independent of initial population (this is rarely the case in reality)
populationChange = sum(YearToModifier(x) for x in range(n_years)) 
#the population in the future is the initialPopulation + population Change ... duh...
populationFuture = populationCurrent + populationChange
print("The Population will be %d!"%populationFuture)
```

there you go

WRT @martjinpeters comment on OP you could change `YearToModifier` to

```
def YearToModifier(x):
    return sum([x%35 ==0,x%7 ==0,-1*int(x%13 == 0)])
```

of coarse as @AshokaLella points out you can calculate the total births/immigrations/deaths for a given number of years without actually visiting each year

```
births = n_years//7
immigrations = n_years//35
deaths = n_years//13
populationChange = births + immigrations - deaths
```

Comment: Your method doesn't increase population by 2 every 35 seconds; there is a birth *and* an immigration, not either. And your method also fails to register both the death and birth at 91 seconds.

Comment: Ah, your second version does do so.

Comment: And please don't use recursion for input validation. A `while True` loop is far more efficient and won't lead to an infinite recursion error when a user tries to enter invalid data forever. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658)